# How to simply stream video from Adobe Flash Media Server? (Linux)

Tags: flash, actionscript, media, flash-media-server

I'm stumped on how to get started with Adobe Flash Media Server.  On Linux.

All I need to do is:

1. Accept a request for rtmp://myserver.com:1935/stream/static/abcdef0123456789
2. Tell FMS that $filename is located at /var/media/ab/cd/ef/abcdef0123456789
3. Have FMS send /var/media/ab/cd/ef/abcdef0123456789 to the client.
4. Handle seeking if necessary.

I know that this is probably 99% of what people want to use FMS for.  However, I'm having a hard time finding a working example.

Can you tell me something like "Put filename.asc in $foldername and enter the following code" please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note flash media server questions should eventually be on ServerFault.com, not SO.

Comment: Reminds me of when I was trying to learn NISplus for Solaris. 99% of its users needed it for its intended purpose: to share user and host information across a network of machines. But Sun wanted it to be a general-purpose database, so all the examples in their huge NISplus tutorials pertained to typical database entities: cars, food, hobbies. Nowhere in their documentation did they mention how to manage the passwd and host entities. What I would have paid for a simple HOWTO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the manual for FMS and configuring storage.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/docs/help.html?content=03_configtasks_32.html#1204236

Comment: So it looks like I will have to just specify the *exact* folder where the file is in.  So instead of "Play abcdef0123456789" it will be "Play ab/cd/ef/abcdef0123456789"

Answer (score 0):

The "vod" directory in "applications" inside of your FMS installation folder is a good place to start. It is set up for easy access to streams to play right out of the box (without having to create a custom application directory to stream from, as we had to do in the past).

So, put the video file in the "media" directory inside of "vod" and then use this as your source for your FLVPlayback component to play it back:

rtmp://localhost/vod/abcd.flv

or, if accessing your server over the web instead of locally:

rtmp://myFMSserverURL.com/vod/abcd.flv